# Is there a way I can see a list of all my YouTube comments over time?

Tags: youtube, comments

I posted something the other day and wish I could find the video again. Is there a way I can see all of my comments?

To save people time, I can tell you that (ATTOW) the answer seems NOT to be https://www.google.com/settings/takeout  ..  I have tried the "YouTube" 'product', and the "Google+ Pages" and "Google+ Stream" 'products', without success.

Comment: @Pacerier I'm guessing ATTOW = At The Time Of Writing

Answer (score 195):

Youtube has added the ability to see all your comment history from the *[Comments on videos history tab (this link will take you there)](https://www.youtube.com/feed/history/comment_history)* from **the Desktop**.

1. Go to Youtube https://youtube.com.
2. Click on Menu in the top-left corner (≡).
3. Depending your screen size you might see two columns layout or one column layout.

   - On the two columns layout, on the right column of the screen,
   - On the one column layout, on top of the screen,

   in the **Manage all history**, click [Comments](https://www.youtube.com/feed/history/comment_history).

Answer (score 6):

[@Stunner's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/101450/126659) really deserves some screenshots, so here goes:

1. Go to https://youtube.com --> click on "History" in the left-hand pane: [image]
2. Now click on "Comments" on the right: [image]
3. Et voilá vos commentaires! (And there are your comments!): [image]
4. Or just click here: https://www.youtube.com/feed/history/comment_history.

Answer (score 3):

My YouTube user name is Siddharth Swaroop.

Therefore, I would conduct a Google search for:

```
"Siddharth Swaroop" site:youtube.com/all_comments
```

Comment: isn't accurate most of my comments don't show up

Comment: this is a nice ideea and it works but ... ONLY AS LONG AS YOU HAVE A **REALLY UNIQUE NAME**, if your name is common enough, you may find millions of results with the same name and worse, with names that contain your name and the actual problem with this solution is the fact that comments don't contain the google/youtube id, but the full name of the user (id is unique, full name is not)

Comment: youtube.com/all_comments redirects to youtube.com. I don't know if that says anything, but is `site:youtube.com/all_comments` valid syntax?

Comment: This does ***not work*** at all. When I tried it, I got two complete unrelated search hits, *"The A's - (12) A Woman's Got Power - YouTube"* and *"The A's - Words [1979] - YouTube"*.

Answer (score 1):

In the upper left corner where it says Upload, click the drop down menu. Then click Analytics. On the bottom left, click inbox. That's where replies to your comments will be.

Comment: Does this still work?