# Is there a way to find comments you made on YouTube?

Tags: youtube, comments

I made a comment on YouTube and want to see if someone replied to it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way I can see a list of all my YouTube comments over time?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/25964/is-there-a-way-i-can-see-a-list-of-all-my-youtube-comments-over-time)

Answer (score 15):

If you simply go to the site https://www.youtube.com/feed/history/comment_history (assuming you are currently logged on to the account from which the comment was made) you can see all comments that you have made.

From that area, you may click on any of the highlighted (and thus, linked) words,  which will be linked according to the content to which they lead.

(Example: Click the linked word "Comment" to go directly to the comment you posted - Click the linked text displaying the "Title of The Video" to go to the page the video is located on, but not necessarily the comment you yourself made.)