# How do I see my comment history on YouTube?

Tags: youtube, comments

I wish to see the comments on videos I've made. When I go to the [comments](http://youtube.com/comments) section on YouTube it only shows me comments made on *my* videos (and I believe it only shows the ones made after the change to Google+). It does not actually show comments that *I've* posted. How can I see a full history of all the comments I've made on YouTube?

I found [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/31960/is-there-a-way-to-find-comments-you-made-on-youtube) post but sadly it is outdated and does not work with the Google+ system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you publicly share every single comment you leave on a video through Google+, you won't be able to find them in a list, so to speak.